# How to check if an attribute of a tag is in even or odd index within attributelist

Tags: jquery

Consider the following code

```
<div id="testdiv" class="selected" lang="en-us" >
<strong>And so it is just like you said it would be</strong>
</div>
```

how can i tell if the 'class' attribute is in even index or odd using jquery? 
like, in here 'class' is in odd index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get attributes of element and find out index

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eSdxm/2/)**

```
function getAttrIndex(elemId, attrName) {
    attrs = document.getElementById(elemId).attributes;
    for (i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++)
    if (attrs[i].name == attrName) return i;
    return -1
}
```

**Edit** based on OP comments, using jQuery

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eSdxm/4/)**

```
function getAttrIndex(elemId, attrName) {
    index = -1;   
    $($('#' + elemId)[0].attributes).each(function (i, item) {     
        if (item.name == attrName) {
            index = i;
            return;
        }
    });
    return index;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i should've mentioned that in my question that I'm looking for a jquery solution.
can you please provide a solution solely done with jquery?

Comment: I do not think there is any thing that would need jQuery any way, change document.getElementById(elemId).attributes to $('#'+elemId)[0].attributes atmost

Answer (score 0):

check the index of class selected by using following code.

```
 var oddSet = $('div.selected:odd').css("property","value");
var evenSet = $('div.selected:even').css("property","value");
```

You can also use filter function for it.

```
$('div.selected').filter(':even') // to get all even elements
$('div.selected').filter(':odd') // to get all odd elements
```

You can apply any function of jQUery of odd or even. which you want.